# Dynamics on prem 8.2 getGlobalContext doesn't work only Xrm.Page.Context works

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016, crm-ribbon-workbench

I want to show the "Run Workflow" ribbon button only to users with system administrator so I use the following JS which work fine in my Dynamics solution:

```
function getrolesarray(formcontextfromribbon) {
    var Globalcontext = Xrm.Page.context;
    var strFirstThree = Globalcontext.getVersion().substring(0, 3);
    var sameunit = true;
    var noclosed_status = true;
    var selview = 0;

    var roleid = Globalcontext.getUserRoles();

    var RoleName_concat = "";

    var user_sysadmin_yesno = false;

    var name;
    for (var i = 0; i < roleid.length; i++) {
        var roleID = roleid[i];
        var RoleName = getRoleName_XMLHttp(roleID,strFirstThree);

        RoleName = RoleName.toUpperCase()

        if ((RoleName == 'SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR')) {

            user_sysadmin_yesno = true;
             
            break;
        }

    }

    return user_sysadmin_yesno;


}

function getRoleName_XMLHttp(roleID,strFirstThree) {
    var roleName = null;
    var param = roleID.toString().replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
    var ajaxurl = Globalcontext.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v" + strFirstThree + "/roles(" + param + ")?$select=_businessunitid_value,name,roleid";
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", ajaxurl, false);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
                var _businessunitid_value = result["_businessunitid_value"];
                var _businessunitid_value_formatted = result["_businessunitid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                var _businessunitid_value_lookuplogicalname = result["_businessunitid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"];
                var name = result["name"];
                var roleid = result["roleid"];
                roleName = result["name"];
            } else {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();

    return roleName;
}
```

If I try to update the deprecated form using the following on line 2:

```
var Globalcontext = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext();
```

It will return undefined, how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Open CRM, open developer tools (by clicking F12), choose "Console", enter Xrm.Utility in the console, hit enter, expand the object you get and check if the getGlobalContext extension is there.

[image]

Upon inspection I found it was not present, and must only be available for version 9.0 and above.